# Youtube Video: SecurityDomain tried to access incompatible context issue

Tags: actionscript-3, api, youtube

I am building a chromeless player with Actionscritp 3 and got the following error when I play certain videos.

SecurityDomain 'http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3' tried to access incompatible context 'http://s.ytimg.com/yt/swf/apiplayer3-vfl181412.swf'

My app can search youtube videos .The error message shows up all the time and some videos can still be played....but some can't...

I already have

```
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
Security.allowDomain("*") 
_loader = new Loader();
```

when I tried to create my player...

I appreciate any help....

Answer (score 0):

Does this ever happen the first time you try to play it?
You might be getting conflicts if you're loading different youtube players in the application domain which have the same definition name.

Try this; when you call load(..) on the loader, create a new ApplicationDomain for the loader context.

```
_loader.load(urlRequest, new LoaderContext(true, new ApplicationDomain(), SecurityDomain.currentDomain);
```

You might have to comment out the `, SecurityDomain.currentDomain` if it throws an error when you test it locally.